# Syncing Office 365 users with a MailChimp List

Tags: powershell, office365, mailchimp

I was reading this guide to ([Sync Office365 users with MailChimp list](https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/sync-office-365-users-mailchimp-list/))
and I am working on creating a sync between company MailChimp account and our licensed users on Office365.
Reviewing the PowerShell script on the site, it looks like one of the prerequisites listed is:

- 'You’ll also need permission to contact these users.'

This is something I do not want to occur. Would rather have this sync complete and have none of the employees notified that they were added to this new Mailchimp list. Is this possible?
I am not too familiar with PowerShell scripting and I don't want to run the script with the possibility of an email being sent to each employee.

Any suggestions on how I can remove that feature from the sync??

The PowerShell script is listed ([here.](https://gcits.com/wp-content/uploads/OwnTenantMailChimpOffice365Sync.txt)):

```
$user = "AnythingGoesHere"
$apiKey = "APIKeyGoesHere"
$pair = "${user}:${apiKey}"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue 
}
$baseUri = "https://us14.api.mailchimp.com"
$listInfo = @{
    listName            = "<removed>"
    company             = "<removed>"
    address1            = "<removed>"
    address2            = ""
    city                = "<removed>"
    state               = "<removed>"
    zip                 = "<removed>"
    country             = "<removed>"
    phone               = "<removed>"
    permission_reminder = "<removed>"
    from_name           = "<removed>"
    from_email          = "<removed>"
    subject             = ""
    language            = "en"
}
$Office365members = @()
Connect-MsolService

function Ensure-MailChimpList ($ListName) {
    $lists = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists?offset=0"&"count=100 -Method Get -Headers $Headers
    if ($lists.lists.name -notcontains $ListName) {
        $list = New-MailChimpList -ListInfo $listInfo
        return $list
    }
    else {
        $list = $lists.lists | Where-object {$_.name -contains $listName}
        return $list
    }
}


function New-MailChimpList ($ListInfo) {
    $listBody = @{
        name                = $listInfo.listName
        contact             = @{
            company  = $listInfo.company
            address1 = $listInfo.address1
            address2 = $listInfo.address2
            city     = $listInfo.city
            state    = $listInfo.state
            zip      = $listInfo.zip
            country  = $listInfo.country
            phone    = $listInfo.phone
        }
        permission_reminder = $listInfo.permission_reminder
        campaign_defaults   = @{
            from_name  = $listInfo.from_name
            from_email = $listInfo.from_email
            subject    = $listInfo.subject
            language   = $listInfo.language
        }
        email_type_option   = $false
    }

    $listBody = $listBody | ConvertTo-Json

    $newList = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Body $listBody
    return $newList
}

function Get-MailChimpListSegments {
    $segments = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/segments?offset=0"&"count=200 -Method Get -Headers $Headers
    return $segments
}

function Get-MailChimpListMergeFields {
    $mergeFields = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/merge-fields -Method Get -Headers $Headers
    return $mergeFields
}

function New-MailChimpListMergeField ($Name, $Type, $Tag) {
    $merge_field = @{
        name = $Name
        type = $Type
        tag  = $Tag
    }
    $merge_field = $merge_field | ConvertTo-Json
    Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/merge-fields -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Body $merge_field
}

function New-MailChimpListBatch ($MemberBatch) {

    $body = @{
        members         = $MemberBatch
        update_existing = $true
    }
    
    $body = $body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

    $batchresult = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Body $body
    return $batchresult
}
function New-MailChimpListMember ($email, $FirstName, $LastName, $Company, $Licenses) {
    
    $merge_fields = @{
        FNAME    = $FirstName
        LNAME    = $LastName
        COMPANY  = $Company
        LICENSES = $Licenses
    }

    
    $member = @{
        email_address = $email
        status        = "subscribed"
        merge_fields  = $merge_fields
    }
    return $member
}
function Update-MailChimpListMember ($ExistingMember, $Office365Member) {
    
    $merge_fields = @{
        FNAME    = $Office365Member.FirstName
        LNAME    = $Office365Member.LastName
        COMPANY  = $Office365Member.Company
        LICENSES = $Office365Member.Licenses
    }

    
    $member = @{
        email_address = $Office365Member.Email
        status        = $existingMember.Status
        merge_fields  = $merge_fields
    }
    return $member
}

function Unsubscribe-MailChimpListMember ($ExistingMember) {

    $member = @{
        email_address = $ExistingMember.Email
        status        = "unsubscribed"
    }
    return $member

    #Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/members/$($existingMember.SubscriberHash) -Method PATCH -Headers $Headers -Body $member
}

function Get-ExistingMailChimpListMembers {
    $existingMembers = $null
    $existingmembers = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/members?offset=0"&"count=100 -Method Get -Headers $Headers
    for ($i = 100; $i -le $existingMembers.total_items; $i += 100) {
        $members = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/members?offset=$i"&"count=100 -Method Get -Headers $Headers
        $existingMembers.members += $members.members
    }
    return $existingMembers
}

function New-LicenseSegment ($SkuPartNumber) {
    $conditions = @()
    
    $conditionproperty = @{
        condition_type = "TextMerge"
        field          = "LICENSES"
        op             = "contains"
        value          = $SkuPartNumber.TrimStart("License: ")
    }
    $conditions += $conditionproperty
    
    $segment = @{
        name    = $SkuPartNumber
        options = @{
            match      = "any"
            conditions = $conditions
        }
    }
    
    $segment = $segment | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
    
    $newSegment = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/segments -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Body $segment
    return $newSegment
}

function Create-ExistingMemberCollection ($ExistingMembers) {
    
    $existingMemberCollection = @()
    foreach ($existingmember in $existingmembers) {
        
        $memberObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Licenses       = $existingmember.merge_fields.LICENSES
            FirstName      = $existingmember.merge_fields.FNAME
            LastName       = $existingmember.merge_fields.LNAME
            Company        = $existingmember.merge_fields.COMPANY
            Email          = $existingmember.email_address
            SubscriberHash = $existingmember.id
            Status         = $existingmember.status
        }
        $existingMemberCollection += $memberObject
    }
    

    return $existingMemberCollection
}

function Create-UploadBatch ($collection) {
    # Upload the collection in batches of 100
    $counter = [pscustomobject] @{ Value = 0 }
    $batchsize = 100
    $batches = $collection | Group-Object -Property { [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $batchSize) }
    foreach ($batch in $batches) { New-MailChimpListBatch -MemberBatch $batch.Group}
}


# Check whether list exists and create it if it doesn't
$listID = (Ensure-MailChimpList -ListName $listInfo.listName).id

# Check for current merge fields in list
Write-Host "Retrieving Merge Fields"
$mergeFields = Get-MailChimpListMergeFields
$updateSegments = $false

$requiredMergeFields = "Company", "Licenses"
foreach ($requiredMergeField in $requiredMergeFields) {
    if (!$mergeFields.merge_fields.Name.contains($requiredMergeField)) {
        Write-Host "Creating Merge Field: $requiredMergeField" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $newMergeField = New-MailChimpListMergeField -Name $requiredMergeField -Type text -Tag $requiredMergeField.ToUpper()
    }
}


# Retrieve existing segments, then filter by license related segments
$existingSegments = Get-MailChimpListSegments
$existingLicenseSegments = $existingSegments | Where-Object {$_.segments.name -match "License: "}
$requiredSegments = @()


# Create collection containing required info for all users in all tenants

Write-Host "Retrieving users and license info" -ForegroundColor Blue
$users = $null
$users = Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.islicensed}
$company = (Get-MsolCompanyInformation).DisplayName
foreach ($user in $users) {
    [string[]]$userLicenses = $null
    foreach ($license in $user.Licenses.AccountSku.SkuPartNumber) {
        $userLicenses += "'$license'"
    }
    $userLicensesString = $userLicenses -join ','
        

    # Check if these licenses already have segments created or queued
    foreach ($license in $userlicenses) {
        $expectedSegmentName = "License: $license"
        if ($existingLicenseSegments.segments.Name -notcontains $expectedSegmentName -and $requiredSegments -notcontains $expectedSegmentName) {
            $requiredSegments += $expectedSegmentName
            Write-Host "Adding $expectedSegmentName to required segments list. Update pending." -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $updateSegments = $true
        }
    }

    $firstName = $user.FirstName
    if (!$user.FirstName) {
        $firstName = $user.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0]
    }
    $lastName = $user.LastName
    if (!$user.lastName -and !$user.firstname) {
        $lastName = $user.DisplayName.Split(" ") | Where-Object {$_ -notcontains $user.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0]}
        $lastName = $lastName -join " "
    }
    elseif (!$user.lastName -and $user.firstname) {
        $lastname = ""
    }
    elseif (!$user.LastName -and !($user.DisplayName.Split(" ") | Where-Object {$_ -notcontains $user.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0]})) {
        $lastname = ""
    }
        
    $email = $user.UserPrincipalName
    $memberObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Licenses  = $userLicensesString
        FirstName = $firstName
        LastName  = $lastName
        Company   = $company
        Email     = $email
    }
    $Office365members += $memberObject
}

Write-Host "Retrieved $($office365Members.count) licensed users" -ForegroundColor Green
# If an update is required, add new segments
if ($updateSegments) {
    Write-Host "New segments required: $requiredSegments" -ForegroundColor Green
    # Create new license segments

    if ($requiredSegments.count -gt 0) {
        foreach ($requiredSegment in $requiredSegments) {
            Write-Host "Creating new segment - $requiredSegment" -ForegroundColor Blue
            $newSegment = New-LicenseSegment -SkuPartNumber $requiredSegment
        }
    }
}

# Check if members exist in list
# Build list of existing members

Write-Host "Getting existing members"

$existingMembers = (Get-ExistingMailChimpListMembers).members

$newMemberCollection = @()

# Check if Office 365 users already exist in mailchimp. If they don't, add them to a collection for upload
foreach ($member in $Office365members) {
    if ($existingMembers.email_address -notcontains $member.Email) {
        Write-Host "Adding $($member.firstName) $($member.lastName) to new subscriber collection" -ForegroundColor Green
        $newMemberObject = New-MailChimpListMember -email $member.Email -FirstName $member.FirstName -LastName $member.LastName -Licenses $member.Licenses -Company $member.Company
        $newMemberCollection += $newMemberObject
    }
}

Create-UploadBatch -collection $newMemberCollection

# Retrieve updated list of existing members

$existingMembers = (Get-ExistingMailChimpListMembers).members
$existingMemberCollection = Create-ExistingMemberCollection -ExistingMembers $existingMembers

# Update users when details have changed.

$updatedMemberCollection = @()
foreach ($existingMember in $existingMemberCollection) {
    $office365Member = $null
    $office365Member = $Office365members | Where-Object {$_.Email -contains $existingMember.Email}
    if ($office365member) {
        if ($office365Member.FirstName -notmatch $existingMember.FirstName -or `
                $office365Member.LastName -notmatch $existingMember.LastName -or `
                $office365Member.Licenses -notmatch $existingMember.Licenses -or `
                $office365Member.Company -notmatch $existingMember.Company) {
            
            Write-Host "Updating record for $($existingMember.Email)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $updatedMemberObject = Update-MailChimpListMember -ExistingMember $existingMember -Office365Member $office365Member
            $updatedMemberCollection += $updatedMemberObject
            
        }
    }
}

Create-UploadBatch ($updatedMemberCollection)

# Unsubscribe users who no longer exist in Office 365

$unsubscribedMemberCollection = @()
foreach ($existingMember in $existingMemberCollection) {
    if ($Office365members.Email -notcontains $existingmember.Email -and $existingmember.status -notcontains "unsubscribed") {
        Write-Host "$($existingmember.Email) is no longer licensed in Office 365, unsubscribing." -ForegroundColor Red
        $unsubscribedMemberObject = Unsubscribe-MailChimpListMember -ExistingMember $existingMember
        $unsubscribedMemberCollection += $unsubscribedMemberObject 
    }
}

Create-UploadBatch ($unsubscribedMemberCollection)
```

I have not tried anything yet as I don't want to run the script and an email is sent to each employee.
Looked online for this type of request to see if an email is sent out but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer your question, several warnings:

- You should **never** run a script you found online that you don't fully understand. If you don't understand it, take the time to learn what you need to learn to understand it (or find someone who can). Perhaps this is a good opportunity to get more familiar with PowerShell—it'll probably be a big help for you later on.
- You should **never** include credentials in a script (which is what this script suggests you to do with your MailChimp API key).
- You should **never** run a script for the first time against all your users. You probably shouldn't even run it for the first time in your real production tenant. Run it in a test tenant first, for test users. Then for test users in your production tenant. Observe the results, check that everything is going like you expect, and only *then* run it for everyone.
- Be very skeptical about an outdated script. The script uses the MSOnline Powershell module, which was long ago replaced by the AzureAD module, which itself has also been replaced now with the Microsoft Graph PowerShell module. Relying on a PowerShell module that has been twice superseded  does not add a lot of confidence.
- The script has issues. For example, it retrieves users using the `Get-MsolUser` cmdlet, without using the `-All` switch. In a tenant with a large number of users, this will only include some of them (the first 100, I believe). I can't say whether there are other issues in the script, but the fact that there is at least one is another reminder you need to review it carefully, and make sure you've tested it.

So, to your question: The script itself does not send any emails. The users are [added to the MailChimp list](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/add-member-to-list/) directly with the `status` property set to `subscribed`, which skips the step where they get an email asking them to confirm their subscription.

Whether adding a user to the list results in an email to the user depends on how the list itself is configured in MailChimp (for example, if it's set up to send an [automatic welcome email](https://mailchimp.com/en/help/create-an-automated-welcome-email/)).

Of course, you'll be able to confirm this is the case once you've understood the script, updated it to be secure and suit your needs, and tested it with a test user.